# Custom permission assignment programmatically in salesforce

Tags: apex, custom-permission

How can we assign custom permission to user via apex coding

Answer (score 5, accepted):

`Custom Permission` cannot be assigned to the user directly. That could be done by means of assigning `Permission Set` to the user. `Custom Permission` should already be assigned to the `Permission Set` :

```
PermissionSetAssignment assignment = new PermissionSetAssignment();
assignment.AssigneeId = userId;
assignment.PermissionSetId= permissionSetId;
insert assignment;
```

or assigning `Custom Permission` to the profile.

Assigning `Custom Permission` to a Profile or Permission Set can be done via salesforce UI, or via Metadata API.

Take a look at [Enable Custom Permissions in Permission Sets](https://help.salesforce.com/s/articleView?id=sf.perm_sets_custom_perms.htm&type=5) and [Enable Custom Permissions in Profiles](https://help.salesforce.com/s/articleView?id=sf.users_profiles_custom_perms.htm&type=5)

Comment: I have to assign custom permission to Button after user creation is it possible

Comment: @Dattashinde you'll need to build custom user management page, where by clicking button you'll assign permission set (to which custom permission is already assigned) to selected user.